# How can I make a shell command execute synchronously in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, zip, command, unzip

I want to extract zip files and delete them when they are extracted. Googling tells me that the easiest way to unzip files in Ruby is to execute them with `unzip filename.zip`. My next step is to delete the zip file.

The second step happens so fast that the shell command unzip does not have a chance to even see the file before it is deleted. It errors out saying

```
"unzip:  cannot find either filename.zip or filename.zip.zip."
```

I just want to have the `unzip...` command complete before continuing execution of the ruby script. I want it to block synchronously. Is there a way to do that? I cannot use sleep because I cannot estimate how long it will take.

Comment: Would be a good idea to show us your code.

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 4):

The usual ways to run an external program in ruby are synchronous so there should be no problem.

Try

```
`unzip`
```

or

```
system("unzip")
```

or

```
system("unzip x && rm x")
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the system("unzip x && rm x") will work. I already solved my problem by using the rubyzip library to unzip. But if I had to execute a shell command, I suppose your trick will work.